# How to Add Grouping and Incremental Loading Support for a GridView in UWP

Tags: wpf, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

Currently I'm able to perform grouping using a **CollectionViewSource** instance that is being binded to a GridView ItemSource. All is working as aspected but I need to add Incremental Loading Support, and I managed to do this in other context using **IncrementalLoadingCollection**, but I'm not sure if this can be done together without making any UI tweaks.

Currently my code is looking like this :

```
<GridView
                    x:Name="test"
                          Margin="18,20,0,0"
                          Grid.Row="3"
                          Loaded="All_GridView_Loaded"
                          SelectionMode="Single"
                          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <GridView.GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle>
                            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate x:DataType="someType">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle>
                    </GridView.GroupStyle>
                    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="someType" x:DefaultBindMode="OneWay">


                           .........
                  </DataTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                </GridView>
```

And the code behind for binding :

```
 var cvs = new CollectionViewSource { IsSourceGrouped = true };
     cvs.Source = some list ....;

     gridView.ItemsSource = cvs.View;
```

Comment: Why does this have tags other than uwp?  Isn't Incrementalloadingcollection unique to uwp?

Comment: @Andy maybe there are other ways of doing it, yes incrementalloadingcollection is uwp specific, but its not mandatory for me, I just try to find out a solution

Answer (score 1):

Try use MVVM Helpers library by James Montemagno, it has `Grouping` and `ObservableRangeCollection` of which you asked for. To see a quick demo watch [his video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLsLCXiNPhI).
Or browse on [Project github](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/mvvm-helpers)